# c1,c2,c3 states still being used with ~90 percent usage on all cores

Tags: windows-10, bios, performance, cpu-usage

When playing battlefield 5 on the high performance power plan i get this with perfmon:

[image: IMG:]

The 6 lines at the top are the core utilization (between 80% and 90%), the 6 lines at the bottom are the c1,c2,c3 states.

Each one got about 30% - even though perfmon only measures once a second this is to much.
Aren't c'states controlled by the BIOS? So the BIOS should detect the load and not put the cpu into a power saving state. Why does it do this?

Hardware:

- i5 8600K
- 1080ti
- 2x16Gb@XMP - i know its overkill, 16Gb are from a second pc for experiments.
- Gigabyte Z370 HD3

Comment: Are you having performance issues when playing Battlefield 5?

Comment: Please add which type of computer (motherboard, CPU, etc.) you are using for more help. The more information people here at Super User has to work with you, better too help you. Thank you.

Comment: @SamForbis sometimes in the middle of a firefight it just "lags" - frametime spikes. i will need to add a second graph from afterburner that shows such spikes...my fault